# Java runtime error as well as load exception error

Tags: javafx

Hi I am getting this error when trying to run my fxml file created in oracle scene builder the fxml file is labelled with the proper names for each of the buttons as well as the controller class being properly labelled, my control code for the in question error looks like this

```
package prog24178;


import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;



import javafx.scene.control.ListView;


public class DataBaseController implements Config{
    @FXML TextField txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4;
    @FXML Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
    @FXML ListView<String> list;
    @FXML private ArrayList<String> stringItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    @FXML private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    
    @FXML
    public void add(ActionEvent e) {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText());
            String item = txt2.getText();
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(txt3.getText());
            double price = Double.parseDouble(txt4.getText());
            items.add(new Item(id, item, quantity, price));
            list.getItems().clear();
            stringItems.clear();
            for(Item item1 : items) stringItems.add(item1.toString());
            ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(stringItems);
            list.setItems(items);
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void load(ActionEvent e) {
        items.clear();
        stringItems.clear();
        list.getItems().clear();
        
        File f = new File(FILE);
        try {
            if(!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();
            Scanner lines = new Scanner(f);
            if(!lines.hasNextLine()) {
                 Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "data file is empty\nenter car and click the save button"); 
                 alert.showAndWait();
            }
            else {
                while(lines.hasNextLine()) {
                    Scanner line = new Scanner(lines.nextLine());
                    line.useDelimiter(":\\s*");
                    items.add(new Item(line.nextInt(), line.next(), line.nextInt(), line.nextDouble()));
                    line.close();
                }
            }
            lines.close();
            
            for(Item item1 : items) 
                list.getItems().add(item1.toString());
                //stringCars.add(car.toString());
            //ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(stringCars);
            //list.setItems(items);
            
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    
    @FXML   
        public void save(ActionEvent e)  {
        File f = new File(FILE);
        try {
            if(!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
            for(Item c : items) 
                pw.printf("%s:%s:%s:%d:%b\n", 
                        c.getID(), c.getItem(), c.getQuantity(), c.getPrice());
            pw.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "data is saved in a file\nyou can close the \napplication now"); 
         alert.showAndWait();
    
    }
    @FXML
        public void modify(ActionEvent e)  {
    

        }
    
    @FXML
        public void remove(ActionEvent e)  {
            
        }
        
        }
```

the RunApp class

```
package prog24178;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RunApp extends javafx.application.Application implements Config{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage ps) throws Exception {
        URL res = this.getClass().getResource("control.fxml");
        Parent scene = FXMLLoader.load(res);
        Scene ourscene = new Scene(scene);
        ps.setScene(ourscene);
        ps.setTitle("Items Database");
        ps.show();
    }
}
```

the implemented config interface

as well as the full error message

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='add', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/C:/Users/Canada%20Computers/workspace/Assign6/bin/prog24178/control.fxml:44

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at prog24178.RunApp.start(RunApp.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application prog24178.RunApp
```

FXML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="384.0" prefWidth="664.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="prog24178.RunApp">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="130.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="51.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="276.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="34.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="253.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="39.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="307.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="203.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="446.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="66.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="446.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="75.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="446.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="51.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="446.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="148.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="48.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="48.0" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="48.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="40.0" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="44.0" minHeight="8.0" prefHeight="32.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="274.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="32.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="274.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="201.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="123.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="31.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" text="ID:" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <TextField fx:id="txt1" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="46.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label text="Item:" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <TextField fx:id="txt2" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="57.0" text="Quanitity:" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <TextField fx:id="txt3" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label text="Price:" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <TextField fx:id="txt4" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </TextField>
      <HBox prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="516.0" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="b1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="add" text="Add Item" />
            <Button fx:id="b2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#modify" text="Modify Item" />
            <Button fx:id="b3" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#remove" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="107.0" text="Remove Item" />
         </children>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets top="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </HBox>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
         <children>
            <ListView fx:id="list" prefHeight="201.0" prefWidth="627.0">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="20.0" right="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </ListView>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <Label text="Items:" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="b4" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#load" text="Load Data From File" />
            <Button fx:id="b5" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#save" text="Save Data To File" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="318.0" text="Database of Items">
               <font>
                  <Font size="26.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
   <opaqueInsets>
      <Insets />
   </opaqueInsets>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Post the relevant FXML file. The stack trace is telling you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PbB_xblqLfIosE8KsrYWKSfRaGNWaCqr/view?usp=sharing  the fxml file used

Comment: Post the code in the question.

Comment: Your controller is pointing to the RunApp not the DataBaseController

Comment: [mcve] please..